# url_launcher not opening app on iOS but works on Android in flutter

Tags: flutter, salesforce, single-sign-on, salesforce-lightning, url-launcher

I am trying to open some native apps e.g. salesforce to done SSO, And I'm using url_launcher package for that. Its working as expected in Android but not working in iOS.
I tried all launchmode.
Here is my code

```
 final uri = Uri.parse(url);
  print("uri is: $uri");
  bool canLaunch = await canLaunchUrl(uri);
  print("can launch $canLaunch)");
  if (canLaunch) {
    await launchUrl(uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
  }
```

Its showing `true` in calLaunch but its not opening the app and keeps open the url in safari.

My url is looks like this one

```
https://sprint48-qa.test.com/Saas/304/user/sso?source=mob&application_id=2515&token=eyzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJBc2h1IiwiaWF0IjoxNjkyNDY5NTE5LCJleHAiOjE2OTI0NzMxMTksInVzZXJpZCI6MTY1NTIsInRlbmFudGlkIjozMDR9.PwLEp4aa6Iael3qUn_SmyUSK0wR8d3ngR4Ta99zWwWw
```

and info.plist is

```
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>http</string>
    <string>https</string>
</array>
```

Comment: what is your URL scheme?

Comment: Thanks. What is the iOS version of your physical device?

Comment: I am testing on iPhone 14.